# ActiveX DLL locks up main UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll, vb6, activex

I'm struggling with running a function from an ActiveX DLL (compiled from VB6) in a background thread from a C# WinForms application.

Because the VB6 DLL project contains a lot of references to an old library called Sheridan Controls (threed32.ocx), which I'm helpfully informed "doesn't support multi threaded mode", I have to set the Threading Model option to Single Threaded (instead of Apartment Threaded) when compiling the DLL in VB6. So even though I set the ApartmentState property to STA on the C# Thread object from which I invoke the DLL, it still ends up clogging up the UI thread.

I'm not sure what my options are at this point. Refactoring out the Sheridan Controls from the DLL would be a tedious job. Another is just to accept defeat and let the UI hang while the DLL does its work.

I guess my main question is; does anyone know of a way I could (without too much hassle) run the single threaded ActiveX DLL in a separate process/service that could be invoked asynchronously from the main C# thread? Or is there any other option that I'm not aware of?

**Solved**: Based on the information from user @mnistic, I was able to find a solution. I had to rebuild the ActiveX DLL as an ActiveX EXE, which runs as an out-of-process component. To get it working I had to set "Start Mode" to "Standalone" in project properties. I also set the Instancing parameter on the VB6 class to SingleUse, to ensure that global state would not be shared across instances.

After updating the project reference, I was able to invoke the functions in the library in background threads from my C# application without causing GUI lag.

Comment: What kind of an ActiveX DLL is this? Is it a control that you're trying to embed within your GUI?

Comment: What means *"clogging up"* ?

Comment: If you are up to no return value, or simple type return value, you could wrap ActiveX in in command line exe, then just 'Shell' your exe with CreateProcess set usynchroniuos = yes..

Comment: @mnistic: No, I'm just using it to call a function that makes some calculations, no GUI involved. However parts of the VB code contain references to ActiveX UI elements so they are still included in the DLL at compile time.

Comment: This is not fundamentally different from the way .NET controls behave.  Except that if you assign their properties from a worker thread then you have some hope of getting an InvalidOperationException and learn to use Control.BeginInvoke().  For ActiveX controls this is entirely automagic.  These controls were made 20 years ago for machines that were about 65 times slower than the one you use now.  So they don't by nature "clog up" anything.  Unless you make the traditional mistake of stuffing them with thousands of items.

Comment: @Sinatr It means that the GUI hangs while the DLL is working.

Comment: @RuneAamodt, what is *"DLL is working"*? Can you explain precisely the problem?

Comment: @TSion.D.P The return value in this case is just a decimal value (Double). Is there an easy way to wrap an ActiveX class/function into a command line exe from VB6?

Comment: Start a command line project in Visual Studio , reference your ActiveX DLL, run the function then return the value as process result

Comment: @Sinatr In the DLL I have a COM class MyClass that has a public function CalculateSomething which returns a value. I want to call this function from C#, which works- but it doesn't run multi-threaded, so the UI thread of the C# application hangs while this function is executing (even if it is started within a separate thread). This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @RuneAamodt, as far as I understand it you can't. If someone stupid enough to make `CalculateSomething` bound to UI thread made it so, then you have to run it in UI thread. Suggestion: show (using another thread, so it will at least repaint itself) winforms form "Calculating now" on top of frozen calculating form.

Comment: No need to start with name-calling. The person who originally wrote this VB code is long since retired. And yes, this function may have been stuffed with a lot more content than it should have. Anyway, it seems wrapping it into a command line exe is actually the simplest option in my case, and then from C# using Process.StandardOutput to get the result.

Comment: The "proper" way of doing this used to be to create an "out of process" component and marshal the data across, but if all you need is this one double value out of it, then wrapping the dll and running with CreateProcess as suggested is good enough.

Comment: @mnistic I just googled a bit around for "out of process" ActiveX component and I think this is actually the solution I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @mnistic After a bit of trial and error with the settings, I was able to get it working wonderfully by building the project as an ActiveX EXE instead of DLL, following your tip. If you care to make your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: All this discussion but almost no votes for the question itself??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to ActiveX, Microsoft differentiates between in-process and out-of-process components. Sometimes when people talk about ActiveX they are referring to in-process components, dll or ocx files that run in the same process as the client that's using them. Typically these components include GUI elements that VB6 made easy to embed within the client application. However, an in-process component must use the client's thread of execution, which in your case was causing the perceived lockup in main thread.

This is what out-of-process components are for. They execute in a separate thread -- separate process as a matter of fact. The drawback is that the communication needs to cross process boundaries, but in your case that's not a concern, and they are relatively easy to set up: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262334%28v=vs.60%29.aspx